# Is it legal to have 2 different standards for "checks within the territory" and when an (internal Schengen) border is crossed in Schengen area?

Tags: germany, borders, schengen

I have noticed that Germany has two different for "checks within the territory" and when an (internal Schengen) border is crossed.

For crossing an (internal Schengen) border Germany is enforcing e.g. Article 13 Border crossing (in general Articles suitable only for external Schengen border).

In my opinion, such practice violates TITTLE III, CHAPTER I of EU 2016/399 "Absence  of  border  control  at  internal  borders" and Article 23 of EU 2016/399 "Checks  within  the  territory"

> Article 23 of EU 2016/399 Checks  within  the  territory:
>
> The  absence  of  border  control  at  internal  borders  shall  not  affect:
>
> (a)   the  exercise  of  police  powers  by  the  competent  authorities  of  the  Member  States  under  national  law,  **insofar  as  the  exercise  of  those  powers  does  not  have  an  effect  equivalent  to  border  checks**;  **that  shall  also  apply  in  border  areas.**  Within   the   meaning   of   the   first   sentence,   **the   exercise   of   police   powers   may   not,   in   particular,   be   considered   equivalent  to  the  exercise  of  border  checks  when  the  police  measures**:
>
> (i)   do   not   have   border   control   as   an   objective;
>
> (ii)   are  based  on  general  police  information  and  experience  regarding  possible  threats  to  public  security  and  aim,  in  particular,  to  combat  cross-border  crime;
>
> (iii)  **are  devised  and  executed  in  a  manner  clearly  distinct  from  systematic  checks  on  persons  at  the  external  borders**;
>
> (iv)  are  carried  out  on  the  basis  of  spot-checks;
>
> (b)  security  checks  on  persons  carried  out  at  ports  and  airports  by  the  competent  authorities  under  the  law  of  each  Member  State,  by  port  or  airport  officials  or  carriers,  provided  that  such  checks  are  also  carried  out  on  persons  travelling  within  a  Member  State;
>
> (c)   **the  possibility  for  a  Member  State  to  provide  by  law  for  an  obligation  to  hold  or  carry  papers  and  documents**;
>
> (d)  the  possibility  for  a  Member  State  to  provide  by  law  for  an  obligation  on  third-country  nationals  to  report  their  presence  on  its  territory  pursuant  to  the  provisions  of  Article  22  of  the  Convention  implementing  the  Schengen  Agreement  of  14  June  1985  between  the  Governments  of  the  States  of  the  Benelux  Economic  Union,  the  Federal  Republic  of  Germany  and  the  French  Republic  on  the  gradual  abolition  of  checks  at  their  common  borders  (‘the  Schengen  Convention’).

**Now, how to define a border control? For me a border control is a control at borders or border area which differs (typically is more strict) from a control within the territory (imagine a police control in a capital city far away from a border).**

Therefore, if there are different standards for a control in border area and within the territory of Germany, in my opinion, this is illegal.

Some would definitely argue that based on Article 23(c) of EU 2016/399 a Schengen state have "the  possibility  for  a  Member  State  to  provide  by  law  for  an  obligation  to  hold  or  carry  papers  and  documents" Again, I argue that based on Article 23 of EU 2016/399 "checks within the territory" have to be the same both in a border area and e.g. in a capital city.

I futher examined Article 23(c) of EU 2016/399:

> Article  42 of EU 2016/399
> Notification  of  information  by  the  Member  States
>
> The  Member  States  shall  notify  the  Commission  of  national  provisions  relating  to  Article  23(c)  and  (d),  the  penalties  as  referred   to   in   Article   5(3)   and   the   bilateral   agreements   authorised   by   this   Regulation.   Subsequent   changes   to   those   provisions  shall  be  notified  within  five  working  days.

The notifications are here (most of countries submitted it 24.1.2008 and then forgot about it, e.g. the Czech republic updated the Czech immigration law but it is not reflected in this notification):

https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:C:2008:018:0015:0024:EN:PDF

Based on analysis of this notification is clear that some countries understand that border controls have been abolished on internal Schengen border by EU 2016/399 (EU 2006/562) and there are only "checks within the teritorry" even in border areas but some countries still setup rules "when a border is crossed" which is, in my opinion, a violation of TITTLE III, CHAPTER I of EU 2016/399 "Absence  of  border  control  at  internal  borders"

Please just compare in the notification Luxembourg and Germany where the difference is clear. In my opinion Germany shall enforce only Article 48 of AufenthG which corresponds to Article 23(c) of EU 2016/399.

Considering Schengen Borders Code EU Regulation 2016/399, is it legal to have 2 different standards for "checks within the territory" and when an (internal Schengen) border is crossed in Schengen area?

Comment: Does this answer your question? Schengen Code **Article 3** *Scope: This Regulation shall apply to any person crossing the **internal or external** borders of Member States* Thus you assumption: *in general Articles suitable only for external Schengen border* is false.

Comment: Schengen Borders Code EU 2016/399 is divided into TITLES. TITLE II is for crossing external Schengen Border and TITLE III is for crossing internal Schengen border. Just to remind you, EU Regulation is to be applied directly and fully. TITLE III talks about abolition of border controls on internal borders. Therefore, I don't see what is wrong with my assumtion. Read Slovakian "Zákon č. 404/2011 Z. z.Zákon o pobyte cudzincov" which is well aligned with EU 2016/399

Comment: I really do not understand why you put here Article 3 of EU 2016/399. Schengen Borders Code indeed regulates both crossing external (TITLE II) and internal (TITLE III) Schengen border but these are 2 different concepts. I am saying that a police control in border area (internal border) has to be exactly the same as in the middle of the country because TITLE III abolishes border controls on internal borders and talks about checks within the territory even in border areas (internal border).

Answer (score -1):

As nobody is answering, I will try to answer this questions and I am looking forward to some discussion.

My answer is that it is **not** legal to distinguish a police control "when an internal Schengen border is crossed" and a police controls "check within the territory". Both controls have to be equivalent, not only whether it looks like a border control or not but also what kind of law provisions are used.

I support my answer by TITLE III, CHAPTER I of EU Regulation 2016/399 "Absence  of  border  control  at  internal  borders" and also by Article 23 of EU Regulation 2016/399 where it is explicitly mentioned that:

"Within   the   meaning   of   the   first   sentence,   the   exercise   of   police   powers   may   not,   in   particular,   be   considered   equivalent  to  the  exercise  of  border  checks  when  the  police  measures:"  "are  devised  and  executed  in  a  manner  clearly  distinct  from  systematic  checks  on  persons  at  the  external  borders;"

Border controls at internal Schengen borders are clearly "devised  and  executed  in  a  manner  clearly  distinct  from  systematic  checks  on  persons  at  the  external  borders", e.g. at internal Schengen borders there are no border crossing points and the border may be crossed anywhere.

Moreover, analysis of notification according to Article 42 of EU Regulation 2016/399:

https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:C:2008:018:0015:0024:EN:PDF

proves that already in 2008 around half of the countries understood that there are no border controls at internal Schengen borders anymore but there are "checks within the territory" even in border areas and these "checks within the territory" may not have an effect of a border control at external Schengen border, **both within the meaning of law provisions and how the controls look like**. I assume that if such notification would be filled today, more countries would understand that there are no border controls at internal Schengen border.

I am quite sure that under original Schengen agreement from 1985 it was possible to distinguish controls within the territory and when an internal Schengen border is crossed but since EU Regulation 2006/562 (Schengen Borders Code) not anymore.

Comment: Independent on whether there is an internal border check or not **all** persons are required to have a valid travel document when crossing **any internal border**. For EU Citizens: valid **national ID** or **Passport** ; for 3rd country citizens a **passport** (and for 3rd country citizens who are residents: **also** a **residence permit/card**). So it doesn't matter where, when or how a check is done.

Comment: All persons are subject to TITLE III of EU 2016/399 when crossing internal Schengen border. TITLE III talks about abolition of border controls and about checks within the territory. Checks even in border area cannot be considered as border controls. You obviously have a problem to understand that Schengen area is a common immigration space with common rules like USA. Based on TITLE III persons are subject to Article 23(c) of EU 2016/399. Nothing more, nothing less. Article 23 applies for checks within the territory.

Comment: Btw. Article 3 of EU 2016/399: This Regulation shall apply to any person crossing the internal or external borders of Member States, **without prejudice 
to:** (a) **the rights of persons enjoying the right of free movement under Union law;** Meaning EU 2004/38/EC. Meaning Article 5(4) of EU 2004/38/EC must be respected independent of what Schengen Borders Code is saying.

Comment: You say that "all persons are required to have a valid travel document" this statement directly violates Article 3(a) of EU 2016/399 and Article 5(4) of EU 2004/38/EC. Have you ever heard about a "principle of proportionality"? CJEU is often using this principle...